# can't run fig up it always gets killed

Tags: npm, vagrant, docker, fig, dockerfile

This is a painful error as it takes a long time to get to this point and there is no visibility into what went wrong.

1. Does anybody have suggests on locating the cause of this crash?
   Logs?
2. I assume downloading the parent container is the main
   bottleneck. Can I short circuit this so that subsequent runs/trials
   don't take as long?

> Step 6 : RUN npm install  ---> Running in 229b1063fec1 npm WARN
>   package.json meanjs@0.3.3 No README data npm WARN excluding symbolic
>   link build/defs-config.json -> ../defs-config.json Killed

EDIT: Looks like THE OOM Killer is getting me. Any adivce on reducing footprint?

> Dec 25 14:15:25 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel:
>   [26892.464675] Out of memory: Kill process 18561 (fig) score 482 or
>   sacrifice child Dec 25 14:15:25 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel:
>   [26892.465195] Killed process 18561 (fig) total-vm:549684kB,
>   anon-rss:489500kB, file-rss:0kB

EDIT: FIG.YML

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
   - db
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
   - "35729:35729"
  volumes:
   - .:/home/app
  environment: 
   NODE_ENV: development
db:
  image: mongo
  ports: 
   - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Can you add or link to your fig file to help debugging?

Comment: @UsmanIsmail - I updated the questions with my fig.yml

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is fig-related or it's a docker issue. Have you tried building the Docker image before `fig up`? Can you post also the Dockerfile to try it?

Comment: I would tag this with `npm` and `vagrant`, I think the issue is more related to those tools. You might just need to increase the memory available to the vagrant box.

Comment: I bumped the memory to 2G and it is not crashing but takes longer than I would expect.

Comment: I'm just starting with my fig journey but I first made sure each Dockerfile builds before incorporating fig. I would do as @jcortejoso suggests. It should help pinpoint the issue.